# Axis limits and "floating" points - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this boxplot I created with ggplot2, I'm trying to end the continuous y-axis at 30 and remove the portion of the axis above 30 (see red bracket in attached picture), while keeping the asterisk positioned at x=1.5, y=35.. Is this possible? Here's the code I'm currently using [updated]:

```
g <- ggplot(methods_forGGP, aes(class, days)) + 
geom_boxplot(stat = "boxplot") +  
stat_summary(fun.y= mean, geom = "point", shape=4, size=4, colour="black") + 
theme_classic()+
theme(aspect.ratio= (2/(1+sqrt(5))), #landscape: golden ratio
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 14, vjust= 2), 
    axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 14, vjust=-0.5), 
    axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12))+ 
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1"="A", "2"="B"))+ 
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,30,5))+ 
labs(x="X", y="Y")+
```

annotate("point", x=1.5, y=35, shape="*", colour="black", size=10)
g
[image: Box Plot Image]

Comment: This is sort of a side note, but does the code you provided really produce that graph? Because I would have thought you'd need some significant `theme` modifications to get it to look like that, and the axis labels don't match what your code says.

Comment: Yeah I removed some of the code I didn't think was relevant to the question, and changed variable names in the code to protect my data (in my rush to post, definitely mislabeled the code). I can provide full code if that will hep

Comment: Updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this can either be done by adjusting the underlying `grob` object, 
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Limit-the-y-axis-line-with-ggplot2-not-the-axis-itself-but-the-line-used-at-the-left-of-the-graph-td4725918.html

or use the `lemon` package to cap the axis line to the last break:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lemon/vignettes/capped-axes.html

Comment: Thanks so much, the code from the lemon package worked well!